# Online vector-based image editor, that doesn't use Flash

Tags: gratis, web-apps, image-editor

I'm looking for a free web based image editor, that doesn't use flash, an alternative to pixlr. It shouldn't require Java runtime to work either.

It should support layers, inserting multiple images into a layer, centralizing an image within a layer and those basic stuff, I don't need advanced stuff.

Comment: Should it be vector-based (like Inkscape) or pixel-based (like Paint)? In other words, should the multiple images that you wrote about be movable after inserting them?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul yes they should be movable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at http://editor.method.ac/

You have no layer overview but you can send the items forward and backward.

Comment: I wonder why is this site blocked in Russia ..\